# When is the best time to Farm in DoTA?

Tags: dota

I've been playing DoTA like a couple of months ago, and I find the game kinda of amusing (altough the infinite number of douches who plays it), but I'm lacking of some sort of map awareness, specifically with the farming theme. I note that many players in early / mid game already have nice items, and I keep a very low amount of mone altough I keep giving last hits and denying. So, which are the signs that I should start farming or when should I farm?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. DotA is a team game, with each hero playing a different role. Some heroes are meant to be farming and others are not. Carries such as Beastmaster, Juggernaut, Mirana, Kunkka etc farm the best and are meant to do so in order to tank in the late game. I'm going to assume that you are playing one of these heroes, and that your team is nicely balanced with other heroes playing the other roles. In that case:

- Early game, do not leave your lane to
  gank too often. Once or twice early
  if you are the solo is ok, but
  remember that the longer you are out
  of lane, the more XP and gold you
  lose. It's doubly bad if your
  opponent is still in lane getting the
  XP and gold that you would've denied. Stay in your lane and FARM FARM FARM. See the section at the end about support heroes though - they can afford to run around a bit more.
- Later on in the game, farm in between
  the big team moments... when the
  other team isn't about to knock down
  a tower, and when your team isn't
  trying a big push.
- When a bunch of their creep attack
  one of your towers but none of your
  opponents are around is always great.
  This may happen mid to late-game when
  your team has just abandoned a big
  push far into the other side of the
  map. The other team will be busy
  mopping up the creep that are in or
  near their base... if you teleport
  back to your tower quickly, you
  should be able to get more gold out
  of the creep than the cost of the
  scroll.
- Jungling / Neutralling can be good
  when there are no waves of enemy
  creep nearby. It is better to do this
  than to push with a wave into an area
  of the map where you will be ganked.
  Always watch the minimap when
  farming... if you can't see their
  heroes, they are coming to gank you.
  Same rules about teamwork apply -
  don't go farm the neutrals when your
  team is pushing together or they will
  rightfully hate on you. The only
  exception would be if you are the
  carry and your team can do ok without
  you for a little while.

If you aren't playing a carry: support heroes like Lion, Warlock etc should be denying/harassing/ganking and NOT taking gold from the carries. If you only have 2 bracers and boots on level 10 but you've been planting wards the whole game, your team will love you. If on the other hand you last hit ten creep with Lion's stun spikes when there's a Nerubian Weaver around that could've put the gold to better use, you'll be very unpopular.

So know what your role is in the team, and don't try to play a role that your hero isn't intended for. A lot of the dbaggery is misdirected rage from people who don't know how to express their frustration that you aren't playing the team role the way their friends do.

Disclaimer: in low level games / LANs people often get the team aspects of DotA wrong, so you may see heroes be played in the wrong roles, or not be used to being ganked so frequently. In those games you should just pick a carry and outfarm everyone.